# Text box in https://support.stackenterprise.co is not dark mode friendly

Tags: bug, dark-mode, stack-overflow-support

I was using dark mode in [Stack Overflow Support portal](https://support.stackenterprise.co/support/home) and noticed this:

[image]

I expected to see a dark text box like Stack Overflow:

[image]

Can the text box in https://support.stackenterprise.co be made dark mode friendly?

Comment: You're hereby awarded the secret badge *Support Portal Gold Tester*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, I'd like to get that editor to work properly in dark mode, but it is not a priority and it probably won't happen any time soon.

Freshdesk does not actually allow us to modify most of the form elements on pages of the portal, which means any changes to it would have to occur via JavaScript rewriting all the form elements on the page or a bunch of extra CSS on top of an already high amount of mess between Freshdesk's default styles and our own Stacks CSS. Not to mention all the icons in the toolbar are explicitly made in black color as PNGs and would require significant effort to change - at least more effort than I have the time to deal with it for now.

The new ticket screen also displays everything in non-dark mode friendly styles.

The dark mode toggle on Freshdesk is a "just because" feature and is not officially supported in any way, so you'll see places where it does not fully work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed answer, animuson! Regarding new ticket screen in support.stackenterprise.co, I don't think it's applicable for Public Q&A support, is it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkF35.png

Comment: No, we try to keep community requests from being submitted there because we don't want to recreate the contact form and Freshdesk can't integrate with some of the automated systems that exist on-site. But anyone can click buttons and view the form.

Comment: Which buttons are you talking about? You mean the "on-site contact" link?

Comment: "Freshdesk does not actually allow us to modify most of the form elements on pages of the portal" has this been raised as issue with their support?

Comment: @Mast It is entirely by-design to prevent clients from breaking critical elements of the portal. Most of what we do on the portal is a lot of workaround hacks due to the limitations of the customization system. Freshdesk may be the most lenient on customization of the support portals I've ever used, but there are inherent limitations on what they can allow before support for it working properly has to move from them to the client using it.